# Extract list in excel based on criteria

Tags: excel

I have a list of names and a list of categories in a table.

Example:

```
Name               Category 1    Category 2   Category 3
Jane Doe           X             X
Bill Smith         X                          X
Eric Hamilton                    X
```

From that list, I want to list the people for each category.

Example:

```
Category 1     Category 2      Category 3
Jane Doe       Jane Doe        Bill Smith
Bill Smith     Eric Hamilton
```

Is there a way I can do this in excel?

Comment: About 20 categories or so.  It's dynamic as the categories will increase over time.  I'd be adding/removing names and changing their categories from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

I found this video which seems to accomplish what I want.  The formula is a bit more complicated than what I was hoping for, but it worked.  I just removed some of the absolute cell references and copied the formula for the number of categories I currently have and it grouped the users properly.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QkHfZtvC7UQ